# XPages UI in Browser and Notes are not the same

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

For test purpose I create 2 XPages to add contacts and view them.
I took a simple example from [David Leedy / Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P33nSNvSlVc).
When I `preview` the 2 XPages in a browser or in Notes it works as expected.

But when I open the application through Notes (Launching Notes, Open IBM Notes application) I get not the view I expected. There is no UI layout, no buttons, no links. Simple some Data, see screenshots

Good View ( done by calling preview in Designer)

[image]

Bad View ( done by opening the application through Notes directly)

[image]

Note : I am not running a local server, simply Domino Designer.
Obviously something is going wrong here. But what ?

I am new to Notes and XPages, so please have mercy ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check the launch options of your NSF to be set to an XPage that displays the view or another "home" page you created. 
Currently your launch option is set to "Restore as last viewed by user" which just means "show me a simple view"